# use std::string as character array

Tags: c++, string

I want to use the `gets()` function for `std::string str`. But I get an error:

> invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

The `strlen()` function on the other hand doesn't give any error when I write

```
int len = strlen(str.c_str())
```

but `gets(NUM.c_str())` gives the error.

Any suggestions? I need to use `std::string` and `gets()` as my character size is unknown.

Comment: One word: "Don't use `gets`."

Comment: @KerrekSB That's three, arguably four words.

Comment: Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead

Comment: Make the world a better place - don't use `gets`.

Comment: `gets` is about the most dangerous function ever invented. Use the C++ `getline()`.

Comment: @nightcracker: You haven't heard me say it yet! :-)

Comment: `#define HACK_ME_NOW(s) gets(s)`

Comment: "I want to use gets() function..." No, you don't. Trust me.

Comment: woooow.....gets() that bad?? ok...getline() it is then. i know to use it for char array, but how to use it for std::string? syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`c_str()` returns a `const` pointer to the string contents, so you cannot use that to modify the string.

Even if you did circumvent that (which you really shouldn't), it would be impossible to change the *size* of the string (as you're trying to do), since that's managed by the `string` object. The best you could do is write over memory that may not be owned by the `string`, causing crashes or other undefined behaviour.

Even if you did have a suitable array to write to, don't use `gets`. There is no way to prevent it from overflowing the buffer, if the input line is too long. It's been deprecated in C since at least 1999.

> Any suggestions?

```
std::getline(std::cin, NUM);
```

Answer (score 5):

Where to begin...

(1) Firstly, `gets` expects a `char*`, but `std::string::c_str()` returns `const char*`. The purpose of `std::string::c_str()` is merely to provide a C-string representation of the string data - it is NOT meant to provide a writable buffer. The function `gets` needs a *writable* character buffer.

(2) Secondly, you can use `std::string` as a writable character buffer using the `[]` operator, by saying:

```
std::string s(100); // create a buffer of size 100
char* buf = &s[0];
```

This is guaranteed to work properly in C++11, however in earlier versions of C++, it is not necessarily guaranteed that `std::string` provide a contiguous memory buffer.  (Although, in practice, it almost always does.)  Still, if you want a buffer, it's better to use `std::vector<char>`.

(3) Finally, don't use `gets`, EVER.  It's ridiculously dangerous and makes your program prone to buffer overflow and shellcode injection attacks.  The problem is that `gets` doesn't include a `size` parameter, so in practice the program will read any arbitrary amount of bytes into the buffer, potentially overflowing the buffer and resulting in undefined behavior.  This has historically been an attack vector for many hackers, [especially when `gets` is used with a stack array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Exploiting_stack_buffer_overflows).  The function `fgets` should be used instead in C, because it lets you specify a maximum read size parameter.  In C++, it's better to use `std::getline`, because it works directly with an `std::string` object and therefore you don't need to worry about the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use gets() function

[gets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) is C. When possible it is better using C++ features

Instead try [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) like this:-

```
std::getline(std::cin, NUM);
```

And as Jrok mentioned in the comments:-

**Make the world a better place - don't use gets**

Comment: Don't use `gets` in C either. It's deprecated, for goo reason.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems with trying to use `gets` in the first place, you cannot use it on a buffer returned from `c_str()` as the buffer is a const char* (which points to the string buffer held by the `std::string` object.  If you insist on using `gets()`, you would need to create your own buffer to read into:

```
char buffer[1024] = {0}; // temporary buffer
gets(buffer); // read from stdin into the buffer
std::string s(buffer); // store the contents of the buffer in a std::string
```

For an explanation and example of why you should never use `gets`:  http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-56.html

A much better approach is to

```
std::string s; // the std::string you are using
std::getline(std::cin, s); // read the line
```